# Webcam only showing blue on Windows 10 running in Oracle Virtual Box on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, windows-10, webcam

I have an Oracle Virtual Box 6.1 running Windows 10 on Ubuntu 20.04. I would like to use a webcam in my Windows 10 running in the VM. I have already installed the Oracle VM [VirtualBox Extension Pack 6.1.26](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) which enabled me to detect the webcam in the VM. However, instead of showing a camera picture, it only shows a blue screen. The device I'm working on is a Dell Latitude 7480.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Does the webcam works fine in the host OS?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yes, the webcam works perfectly fine on Ubuntu 20.04 (and it also worked just fine on Windows 10 back in the days where I used dual boot instead of VMs on the same device).